# For 0/1 classic kanpsack with 1 bag ( capacity: 2V) or 2 bags (each capacity: V), which choice is better?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I think this is a variant of classic 0/1 knapsack problem. 
That is to say, assume you plan to steal some treasure with given capacity limit(Say 2V). But for the given capacity limit, you have 2 choices: 1 bag with capacity 2V, or 2 bags with capacity V sepetately. Is there any mathmatical formula we can use to pre-compute which solution is better(give us a better optimal value)?  Or we have to compute the optimal value seperately via different recurrence regulation and choose the better one?

More over, we can generalize this problem into the one: given a capacity limit(V), you can take 1 bag with capcity V or take k bags with capcity V/k to conduct stealing. And eonchoose the best one to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

One bag is always better. The content of an n bags solution can always fit into one bag, but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Lior. I also think one bag is better when I consider a extreme condition that for a particular item with capacity 2v, in this case, you can carry it if you have one bag with 2v capacity.  But you give me a deeper view. I think the set of solution to n bags is a subset of set to one bag. Thanks a lot.